# API request stored in service Angular 1

Tags: angularjs, http

I have an application with a parent controller called DashboardCtrl, and multiple child controllers (DashboardBuyerCtrl, DashboardSellerCtrl...)

I'd like to be able to share the results of an HTTP request between the different controllers.
At the moment, I'm executing my HTTP request in every controller, but I think that this is not ideal performance wise.
I've read that I should use service, but I'm stuck here.

can anyone help?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using services is, in general, a good practice because helps you to organize and share the code across your application, I've created a small app to showcase how services could be created and reused in controllers:

```js
var app = angular.module('testApp', []);

app.controller('ctrlA', function($scope, getIp) {
  getIp().then(function(resp) {
    $scope.data = resp.data.origin;
  });
});

app.controller('ctrlB', function($scope, getIp) {
  getIp().then(function(resp) {
    $scope.data = resp.data.origin;
  });
});

app.service('getIp', function($http) {
  return function() {
    return $http.get('https://httpbin.org/ip');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="testApp">
  <div ng-controller="ctrlA">
    First controller
    <p>IP: {{data}}</p>
  </div>
  <div ng-controller="ctrlB">
    Second controller
    <p>IP: {{data}}</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Regarding performance, I'd suggest using [caching](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#caching) option if content is not being updated frequently(or not updated at all), like so:

```
$http({
  url: '...',
  method: 'GET',
  cache: true
});
```

This will save request's response for future use.

You can read more about services in the [official documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services).

Comment: thanks for the very complete answer. I do have a question still. In my case ctrlB is a child of ctrlA, and even though my content is getting updated quite regularly, I know that when I'm using content in ctrlB it's going to be the same as the one in ctrlA. Should I still call the service twice ? In the example that you have provided, let's say that you weren't fetching the ip, but something a tad more dynamic (let's say the current date)  would you really call the service twice ? shouldn't we "share" the content between both controller ?

Comment: You're welcome, in case if you need to share data from parent to child, you should use [components](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component) because it allows proper nesting and parameters passing. Keep in mind that one-way flow(from parent to child) is strictly recommended, for two-way flow you still should use services. Also, all services are singletons, which means that if you set variables inside of them it will be kept as is and could be modified or/and retrieved from any other source(which is the case for current date). Let me know if you have any other questions!

Comment: thanks for the prompt answer. I shall start digging on components.